# Related DropdownButtons and raising onChange event

Tags: flutter, state, refresh, dropdown

I have two `DropdownButton` widget. Content of second one depends on first one selection. Second `DropdownButton` will initiate refresh of third widget. How can I initiate refresh of second `DropdownButton` when first one is populated? And then how can I refresh third widget when second `DropdownButton` populated also?

```dart
class ParentBloc {
  Stream<List<Parent>> get items => _controller.asyncMap(...);

  Future<List<Parent>> _callApi() {
    // call endpoint /parents
  }
}

class ChildBloc {
  ChildBloc(this.parentId);

  int parentId;

  Stream<List<Child>> get items => _controller.asyncMap(...);

  Future<List<Child>> _callApi() {
    // call endpoint /parents/$parentId/children
  }
}

// This bloc created at init state
ParentBloc parentBloc;

// This bloc will be created only after value will
// be selected in the Parent dropdownbutton because
// I need to know `parentId`.
ChildBloc childBloc;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  parentBloc = ParentBloc();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Row(
    children: [
      StreamBuilder<List<Parent>>(
        stream: parentBloc.items,
        builder: (context,snapshot) {
          return DropdownButton(
            items: snapshot.data.map((item) {
              return DropdownButtonItem();
            }),
          );
        }
      ),
      // Content of this widget depends on above one
      StreamBuilder<List<Child>>(
        stream: childBloc.items,
        builder: (context,snapshot) {
          return DropdownButton(
            items: snapshot.data.map((item) {
              return DropdownButtonItem();
            }),
          );
        }
      ),
      // Content of this widget depends on above one
      StreamBuilder<List<Grandchild>>(
        stream: grandchildBloc.items,
        builder: (context,snapshot) {
          return ListView(),
          );
        }
      ),
    ]
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided you're doing this inside a `StatefulWidget`, you can use `setState` inside one of your functions where you update the variables that in turn have to be used to control what is currently displayed in each of your widgets.

It should look something like this (inside your Dropdown):

```
onChanged: (newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    _currentSelection = newValue;
                  });
                },
```

Update: after discussion in the comments, here's a working example that I made of how something can be updated based on a value selected inside a dropbox, hope it helps:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ExampleWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExampleWidgetState createState() => _ExampleWidgetState();
}

class _ExampleWidgetState extends State<ExampleWidget> {

  List<String> someStringsToSelectFrom = [
    'value1',
    'value2',
    'value3',
  ];
  
  String selectedValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Select something:'),
            DropdownButton<String>(
              value: selectedValue,
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.arrow_downward,
                color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
              ),
              iconSize: 24,
              elevation: 16,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 30.0,
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
              underline: Container(
                height: 2,
                color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
              ),
              onChanged: (String newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedValue = newValue;
                });
              },
              items: someStringsToSelectFrom.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: value,
                  child: Text(value),
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
            Text('This will update after you selected a value:'),
            someStringsToSelectFrom.contains(selectedValue) ? Text(selectedValue + ' was selected') :
                Text('Still waiting for user action.'),
            ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you read my question? Please do it again. I know how to refresh the current state of widget. Content of second *dropdownbutton* `depends` on selected value of first dropdownbutton. When widget `build` is executed it render `both` widgets at once! But second one does not know what value is in the first *dropdownbutton* because it is just building. I.e. for the first time second dropdownbutton will show something like `waiting for value`. After first one is built I need to initiate rebuilding of second dropdownbutton. And then second dropdownbutton will initiate building of third widget.

Comment: Then you can do something like `firstDropdownValue != null ? buildSecondDropdown() : showWaitingText(),` and then when the value updates this will also.

Comment: What `something` exactly?
How can I initiate refresh of second DropdownButton when first one is populated?

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's hard to be specific since I'm making guesses instead of looking at a piece of code, could you maybe share the problem bit? It would certainly make the problem more clear. Above I meant that you can have placeholder that way instead of the second dropdown until the needed value is updated.

Comment: What of specific do you mean? I need an approach. I added some code to question but I don't understand how it may helps? I don't need to fix my code. I need a way. I asked `how to initiate build of dependent widget`. For example fisrt StreamBuilder waits until stream with `List<Parent>` will ready. But second one will be crashed because childBloc is not initialized yet.. because there is no selection on first dropdown. Well, suppose I implemented some place holder for second dropdown. First StreamBuilder is built (i.e. drawn). How can I select a value and rebuild second StreamBuilder etc?

Comment: Seeing code does help. I've updated the answer, you can just copy/paste in empty dart file and check out the method I used. It can be applied to your code too.